# How to prevent DataGrid from rebuilding rows after its visibility changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have window with multiple `UserControl`s inside. All of the controls are invisible at  the beginning however user can choose from `ListBox` which control should be visible. Every `UserControl` contains `DataGrid` with some data. Every time the `visibility` of the `UserControl` changes to `Visible`,  `DataGrid` seems to rebuild its content/rows. I want to prevent that because it hits the performance badly.

How to prevent `DataGrid`s from rebuilding rows every time their visibility is changed?

Below is the example:

```
<Window x:Class="Core.View.Windows.MainWindow" ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        ...
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        ...
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <ListBox ...>
            ...
        </ListBox>

       <UserControl1 Visibility="{SomeBindingWithConverter}" />
       <UserControl2 Visibility="{SomeBindingWithConverter}" />
       <UserControl3 Visibility="{SomeBindingWithConverter}" />
       <UserControl4 Visibility="{SomeBindingWithConverter}" />
       <UserControl5 Visibility="{SomeBindingWithConverter}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What makes you think that the rows are rebuilt? Please provide a repo of that demonstrates this behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @mm8 I might have used wrong word, but I can see that rows are not inside grid (are not visibile?) when I change to `UserControl` and appear shortly after when `IsAsync` of `ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Use virtualization, if you are looking for speed in using `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
          EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: That's not the case. I want to load rows once not load them fast everytime `DataGrid`'s visibility change.